# Erro ao executar no Xcode 6 um app criado no Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, conversão

Tenho um app que executa perfeitamente no Xcode 5. Para efeito de atualização, instalei o Xcode 6 e fui executar o mesmo app (sem desinstalar Xcode 5). 
Daí, encontrei alguns problemas, dentre eles:

1) O app executa somente na orientação Landscape. No xcode 5 para tomar a largura da tela eu uso self.view.frame.size.height. Já no xcode 6 tenho que usar self.view.frame.size.width.

2) O app usa UISplitViewController e há um botão que mostra ou esconde o master view. No entanto, no Xcode 6 com o master view escondido, se eu tocar a tela e arrastar o master view aparece e o app é executado de forma incorreta. Neste caso, acredito que o problema possa ser causado pelo método `shouldHideViewController` que foi obsoletado no iOS8. No entanto, o target no meu app é 7.0.

Talvez sejam dúvidas muito específicas, mas alguém pode conhecer estes problemas.

Última dúvida, um app criado no Xcode 5 pode ser executado no iOS8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns pormenores para te ajudar a entenderes melhor o processo de **xCode/SDK/IOS**.

Com o **xCode 6**, começas-te a criar aplicações com o **SDK8**.

Contudo, **SDK** e **target mínimo** da aplicação são coisas distintas, isto é, o SDK é um conjunto de frameworks/Api onde o teu código irá executar, e no caso so SDK8 adiciona funcionalidade para o **iOS8**, contudo podes perfeitamente o **iOS 7** no **SDK8**.

Dito isto, és obrigado a suportar o iOS8 na tua aplicação(e usar o novo xCode6/SDK8), o que provavelmente irá provocar muitas dores de cabeça (falo pela minha experiência) para suportar as novas funcionalidade e antigas.
No maiores dos casos terás que adicionar algo como:

```
  NSOperatingSystemVersion ios8_0_1 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){8, 0, 1};
   if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios8_0_1]) {
      // iOS 8.0.1 and above logic
   } else {
      // iOS 8.0.0 and below logic
   }
```

Sobre os problemas que mencionas-te, no momento que o dispositivo vai mudar de orientação, antes do iOS8, obtinhas o tamanho da orientação **pré orientação**, com o iOS8 recebes a orientação para qual este irá mudar **apos rotação**. Uso isto numa aplicação minha.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0) {
    //implicitly in Portrait orientation.
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        CGRect temp = CGRectZero;
        temp.size.width = fullScreenRect.size.height;
        temp.size.height = fullScreenRect.size.width;
        fullScreenRect = temp;
    }
}
```

Espero que te ajude

Comment: Vai ajudar muito. Perfeito! Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo.